# Regarding attr_accessor and def initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to add school names to array using attr_accessor.

My question is what 'def initialize()' is doing in this case

so that I can store data by using

v1.school_name[0] = "myschoolname"

If I omit the  initialize() function I get the error

```
class StoreData

   attr_accessor :school_name
   def initialize
      @school_name = []
   end
end


v1 = Store_data.new 
v1.school_name[0] = "myschoolname"
print v1.school_name[0] 
v1.school_name[1] = "myschoolnamehighschool"
print v1.school_name
```

Comment: Note: Omit argument lists with nothing in them, so `def initialize` without `()`, and try to name things like `StoreData` instead of `Store_data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

attr_accessor is just an attribute and by default it is nil. You cannot assign any value to it. If you need it to an array then initialize it as an array before using it.

Comment: Regarding "`attr_accessor` is just an attribute", isn't it a method?

Answer (score 3):

In this case you're initializing the `@school_name` with an empty array. If you don't do that it doesn't automatically create it, but it could. That pattern's called *lazy initialization*:

```
class StoreData
  def school_name
    @school_name ||= [ ]
  end
end

s = StoreData.new
s.school_name << "Name 1"
s.school_name << "Name 2"
s.school_name
#=> [ "Name 1", "Name 2" ]
```

You can't assign something to a `nil` value which is what instance variables are by default.

This one creates an array if necessary using the `||=` operator.